# Warning for variables with function names in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, variables, warnings, variable-assignment

Sometimes I accidentally declare variables that have the name of a function.

Here is a constructed example:

```
 max(4:5) % 5
 max(1:10)=10*ones(10,1); % oops, should be == instead  of = 
 max(4:5) % [10 10]
```

At the moment I always find this out the hard way and it especially happens with function names that I don't use frequently.

Is there any way to let matlab give a warning about this? It would be ideal to see this on the right hand side of the screen with the other warnings, but I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Matlab allows you to overload built-in functionality, you will not receive any warnings when using existing names.

There are, however, a few tricks to minimize the risk of overloading existing functions:

- Use `explicitFunctionNames`. It is much less likely that there is a function `maxIndex` instead of `max`.
- Use the "Tab"-key often. Matlab will auto-complete functions on the path (as well as variables that you've declared previously). Thus, if the variable auto-completes, it already exists. In case you don't remember whether it's also a function, hit "F1" to see whether there exists a help page for it.
- Use functions rather than scripts, so that "mis-"assigned variables in the workspace won't mess up your code.

Comment: The tab trick is indeed a nice way to check if a word that you want to use is 'clean'. Still it may give false negatives if a variable has already been put in the workspace.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Using functions instead of scripts remedies this. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure mlint can also check for that.

Generally I would wrap code into functions as much as possible. That way the *range* of such an override is limited to the scope of the function - so no lasting problems, besides the accidental assumption of course.

Comment: I have tried to find it in the mlint preferences, but without success. 
Even after enabling all options a simple test file was still without mlint warning: max=2:10; 
result=max(3:4);

Is there perhaps a more advanced way to change mlint settings that are not in the preference screen?

Comment: I see the specific warning is not there. But there's two that will help to identify such problems: *Variable <name> is used but might be unset (script)*, warns at the first use of `max`. Also one typically stores the results in a variable and `a = max(1:10)=10*ones(10,1)` would be marked as error.

Comment: I guess it only bothers me if I try to do some quick evaluations in the command window. At least this comment assures me that it is not likely to sneak into my code unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, check:

```
exist max
ans = 
  5
```

Looking at `help exist`, you can see that "`max`" is a function, and shouldn't be assigned as a variable.

```
 >> help exist
exist  Check if variables or functions are defined.
exist('A') returns:
  0 if A does not exist
  1 if A is a variable in the workspace
  2 if A is an M-file on MATLAB's search path.  It also returns 2 when
       A is the full pathname to a file or when A is the name of an
       ordinary file on MATLAB's search path
  3 if A is a MEX-file on MATLAB's search path
  4 if A is a MDL-file on MATLAB's search path
  5 if A is a built-in MATLAB function
  6 if A is a P-file on MATLAB's search path
  7 if A is a directory
  8 if A is a class (exist returns 0 for Java classes if you
    start MATLAB with the -nojvm option.)
```

Comment: I guess this could help me to check some variables in hindsight if i am facing a strange problem: Stopping the program, saving a list of all variable names, clearing all variables and then using exist on all of the names.
However, it would be nicer to have a method that can warn me before the problem occurs.